# Extract sentences of text file and put in a dataframe

Tags: python, design-patterns, text

Given a .txt file:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
data = file.read()
```

with a text that looks like:

> "table products section: `<bold>`'This is the section A'`</bold>` introduction:
> 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is subsection A1'`</bold>` content:
> 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is subsection A2' `</bold>` content:
> 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is subsection A3'`</bold>` content:
> 'blablabla' section: `<bold>`'This is the section B'`</bold>`
> introduction: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is subsection
> B1'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is subsection
> B2'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla' section: `<bold>`'This is the section
> C'`</bold>` introduction: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is
> subsection C1'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is
> subsection C2'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is
> subsection C3'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla' subsection: `<bold>`'This is
> subsection C4'`</bold>` content: 'blablabla'"

I need to extract the sentences of 'section' and 'subsection', and put them in a table. Expected output:

```
section                   subsection
'This is section A'       'This is subsection A1'
'This is section A'       'This is subsection A2'
'This is section A'       'This is subsection A3'
'This is section B'       'This is subsection B1'
'This is section B'       'This is subsection B2'
'This is section C'       'This is subsection C1'
'This is section C'       'This is subsection C2'
'This is section C'       'This is subsection C3'
'This is section C'       'This is subsection C4'
```

So, basically, the code should look for the word 'section' then retrieve what's between `<bold>` and `</bold>`, then look for any 'subsection' after this 'section' and also retrieve what's between `<bold>` and `</bold>`. If no more 'subsection', do the same with next 'section' you find in the text, and so on. Until no more 'section'.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Step 1: Use BeautifulSoup to extract everything inside `<bold>` tags. Step 2: Use keyword search to find sub/sections. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "table products section: <bold>'This is the section A'</bold> introduction: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection A1'</bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection A2' </bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection A3'</bold> content: 'blablabla' section: <bold>'This is the section B'</bold> introduction: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection B1'</bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection B2'</bold> content: 'blablabla' section: <bold>'This is the section C'</bold> introduction: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection C1'</bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection C2'</bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection C3'</bold> content: 'blablabla' subsection: <bold>'This is subsection C4'</bold> content: 'blablabla'"

pattern = "(?:<bold>)(.*?)(?:<\\/bold>)"
text = list(map(str.strip, re.findall(pattern, text)))

result = [('section', 'subsection')]
for i in text:
    if 'subsection' in i:
        result.append((section, i))
    else: section = i
```

list of tuples from regex/loop:

```
[('section', 'subsection'),
 ("'This is the section A'", "'This is subsection A1'"),
 ("'This is the section A'", "'This is subsection A2'"),
 ("'This is the section A'", "'This is subsection A3'"),
 ("'This is the section B'", "'This is subsection B1'"),
 ("'This is the section B'", "'This is subsection B2'"),
 ("'This is the section C'", "'This is subsection C1'"),
 ("'This is the section C'", "'This is subsection C2'"),
 ("'This is the section C'", "'This is subsection C3'"),
 ("'This is the section C'", "'This is subsection C4'")]
```